# most efficient practice for RecyclerViews items layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

let's say we have few types of data we want to display, for example, image and text, some items have text some have images and others might have both.

would it be better to create three layouts, one with image view to display images, and another layout with text view to display the text, a third layout for data that has images and text, I choose the layout based on the data that I have.

Or would it be better to just make one layout with both the image view and the text view, set the visibility of whichever view that I want to use to visible and set the other view's visibility to gone.

I prefer the hiding method as it is easier to implement but is it efficient? if we have 100 items with only text that means we will have a 100 image view that we're not using.

this is a simple example, please take into count that there might be more than one view in the layout not being used and is just hidden, thank you in advance.

Comment: Handling visibility is the easier than 3 layouts and if some view's visibility is gone it won't effect the performance of the app  or not gonna take more memory of size of the app.

Comment: no, you can have even million items and still there will be less than dozen image views used by `RecyclerView` - it simply recycles its views (as its name suggests)

Comment: @Sagargujarati I agree with you, it would be much easier to show and hide the component that I need/don't need, but is there something that supports our assumption? I'm hoping for proof so I won't have any doubts

Comment: you want a proof that you will not have 100 image views?

Comment: I want a something to proof that hiding components is as efficient as creating seprate layouts (device performance)

Comment: it is not as efficient as creating separate layouts - but it is a fraction of milliseconds so nobody will notice the difference

Comment: It isn't about showing and hiding, device will still have to create the image view or the text view, it still has to go through that process, of course 1 or 10 items won't effect the device that much but let's say we have 100 or 1000 items, the device will have to create the whole layout even if we won't use it, I believe that the seprate layout is more efficient but I am looking for a proof

Comment: no, you can have even million items and still there will be less than dozen image views used by `RecyclerView` - it simply recycles its views (as its name suggests) - and the proof of that is to add some `Log.d` call inside `RecyclerView.Adapter#onCreateViewHolder` method

Comment: Separating layouts and including them in different layouts won't yield any performance benefits. What you should be looking for in making your layout as light as possible, A.K.A minimal layout sandwiching, preferably 1-2 times overdraws.

Comment: Have you tried profiling?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, @pskink you're right having 1000 data or 100 would be the same as RecyclerView will reuse the layouts, but I'm not sure about what's going on in the background when reusing the layout, I will try to profile the application as Thomas Cook suggested and check the differences in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some test and I monitored performance as the components loaded inside the RecyclerView, First I loaded several items inside my RecyclerView without adding any extra hidden views, then I reran the application but this time I added several hidden views to each of the items, Lastly, I reran the application but this time I displayed the views that I was hidden in my 2nd test. 
From what I've seen, the amount of memory being used by the device depends on the number of views that are being rendered on the screen, having extra hidden items on your screen won't add to your memory usage, what matter is how many items are currently visible on the screen.
As for the power used it is almost identical in all cases the difference, the same goes for the processor usage.

Hope this helps those who were curious like me, and if I'm wrong please feel free to correct me :)